# How to redirect a URL and remove parameters using .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url-parameters, query-string

I'm trying to redirect a URL ending with parameters to another URL without those parameters.

`https://example.com/newsroom/news-events/news.html?L=1&tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=29&tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=detail&cHash=1a27801759cdd648cfd823643ab0e2e1`

to

`https://example.com/en/news/news/`

How can I do that?

Comment: "to same url..." - The example you posted is an entirely _different_ URL? Please clarify. By "ending parameter", are you referring to the _query string_? Do you need to match the source URL (and _query string_) exactly?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is a different URL. I need to the result to  be `en/news/news/`  without a query string.

Comment: How did you get on with my answer?

Answer (score 4):

To redirect the exact URL as stated you will need to use mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond` directives) since only mod_rewrite is able to match the query string part of the URL (ie. everything after the first `?`).

Try the following near the top of the `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =L=1&tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=29&tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=detail&cHash=1a27801759cdd648cfd823643ab0e2e1
RewriteRule ^newsroom/news-events/news\.html$ /en/news/news/ [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The `QSD` flag (Query String Discard) on the `RewriteRule` directive is necessary in order to *discard* the original query string from the redirected response. Otherwise, the original query string is passed through as-is and you would end up with `/en/news/news/?L=1&tx_news_pi1%5Bnews.....`

The preceding `RewriteCond` (condition) directive matches the entire query string exactly as stated. The `=` prefix on the *CondPattern* (2nd argument) makes this an exact string match, as opposed to a regex match.

To match *any* query string, including an entirely empty query string, then simply remove the `RewriteCond` directive.

`R=302` - Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. If this is intended to be permanent then change this to `301` - but only once you have confirmed this is working as intended since 301s are cached persistently by the browser which can result in potential caching problems.

Note also that if you have existing directives in `.htaccess` then the order of these directives can be important.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

---

> a url with ending parameter to url without that parameter

Strictly speaking, the "ending(sic) parameter" would be interpreted as just `cHash=1a27801759cdd648cfd823643ab0e2e1` in the example URL stated, ie. the last URL parameter. All the URL parameters together, make the "query string", which I believe is what you are referring to.